# dropdownList doesn't displays selected value

Tags: asp.net

I am new at asp.net. I have a dropdownList which displays all categories for a specific article. The problem is that when I want to edit an article it doesn't displays the value that exists as default selected in dropdownList.

```
protected void datalist2_OnItemCreated(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem)
    {
        DropDownList drpdKategoria = e.Item.FindControl("drpdKategoria") as DropDownList;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        string Qry = "select * from kategoria";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Qry, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        drpdKategoria.DataSource = ds;
        drpdKategoria.DataValueField = "id";
        drpdKategoria.DataTextField = "emertimi";              
        drpdKategoria.DataBind();
        drpdKategoria.SelectedValue = drpdKategoria.Items.FindByText(Qry).Value;
        //drpdKategoria.Items.FindByValue(string val).Selected = true;
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
        ds.Dispose();
        da.Dispose();
    }
}
```

EditArtikull.aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700">Kategoria</asp:Label>
    <fieldset>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdKategoria" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="false"></asp:DropDownList>               
    </fieldset>
    <br/>
```

> **ERROR:SystemNullReference Exception {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}**

Comment: On what line do you get that error?  When you debug this, which object is `null`?

Comment: on this line     drpdKategoria.SelectedValue = drpdKategoria.Items.FindByText(Qry).Value;

Comment: I want to display as default value  selected in dropdown the value that exists in db

Comment: drpdKategoria.Items.FindByText(Qry).Value is where the issue can arise. If drpdKategoria.Items.FindByText(Qry) does not find anything, ".Value" will error out.

Comment: but i have data in database. I think that instead of Qry i should put the value but I don't know how

Comment: show your .aspx of datalist and its itemtemplates

Comment: insead of qry should be id and emertimi that are in db. How to do this?

Comment: Why you can't do it in the codebelow?

Comment: Side note- you could consider the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/yh598w02.aspx) on your connection, dataset and data adapter. It implements `IDisposable` so you don't need to close and dispose manually

Answer (score 1):

This line probably isn't going to find anything:

```
drpdKategoria.Items.FindByText(Qry)
```

Since `Qry` is a SQL statement:

```
string Qry = "select * from kategoria";
```

And I'm *assuming* that the display values in your `DropDownList` aren't SQL queries.  Thus, when you call `.Value` on that first line, you're trying to de-reference something that isn't found (which is `null`), hence the error.

What item are you actually trying to find?  If you want to select a default item, you need to be able to *identify* that item in some way.  In your data that would be either by a known `id` value or a known `emertimi` value.  For example, if you have a known `emertimi` value, it would be:

```
drpdKategoria.SelectedValue = drpdKategoria.Items.FindByText("some known value").Value
```

To make this a little more robust, you probably want to add some null checking.  Something like this:

```
var defaultValue = drpdKategoria.Items.FindByText("some known value");
if (defaultValue != null)
    drpdKategoria.SelectedValue = defaultValue.Value
```

Comment: i want id as DataValueField and emertimi as DataTextField

Comment: + 1 for null checking, you beat me to it.

Comment: @user3592644: You're already using those as your `DataValueField` and `DataTextField`, the error has nothing to do with that.  The error is that you're looking for a *SQL string* in your values, which isn't present among those values.

Comment: var defaultValue = drpdKategoria.Items.FindByText("emertimi");
                if (defaultValue != null)
                    drpdKategoria.SelectedValue = defaultValue.Value;

Comment: @user3592644: Is there a value called `"emertimi"` in the `DropDownList`?  That's the name of the *column* from which you're selecting values, is it *also* one of the values?  If you want to select a specific record, you need to be able to *identify* that record in some way.  You can't just tell it the *column* to select and expect it to know which *row* you want.

Comment: but how to do this? I have 2 tables "articles" and "categories". Dropdown displays all "emertimi" from categories table. When i click one calue it saves id of that categorie in table "article". Now how can I display emertimi selected for a specific article?

Comment: @user3592644: Think of it this way... You have a table with 3 people in it: Dave, John, and Mike. You're telling the `DropDownList` to use `Name` as the `DataTextField`, so for your 3 options you would see `Dave`, `John`, and `Mike`. If you want to pre-select a *specific* person, you need tell it *which* person to select. Currently you're telling it to pre-select `Name`. Every record has a `Name`. You need to tell it to select either `Dave` or `John` or `Mike`. In order to select a value, you need to *know* the value you're trying to select.

Comment: well ok i understand this. but the problem is i don't know the way to do it :( ok now i have all values for that article string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
                string Qry2 = "select * from artikulli where id='" + id + "'"; now how to select "emertimi" from categories based on value "article.categoria_id"=categoria.id. how to save as var the column categories_id of that article?

Comment: @user3592644: If you have the ID of the item you want to select, then use that as the value to select.  You have this: `string id = Request.QueryString["id"];`  Does that correspond to an `id` in the `DropDownList`?  If so, then you should be able to do this: `drpdKategoria.SelectedValue = id;`

Comment: no that's not the id in dropdown. This is ID of ARTICLE I want id and emertimi of categorie of that article. id of categorie is saved as categorie_id in article table. based on that value i should find emertimi and if from table "categories"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52236/discussion-between-user3592644-and-david)

Comment: @user3592644: I recommend creating another Stack Overflow question specifically identifying the problem you're describing and providing more information about what you're trying to achieve, including the values known to the page (from the query string, for example) and the table structures of your data.  This conversation has extended well beyond the scope of the error you were receiving in this question.  Stack Overflow questions are about specific issues, not ongoing tutorials.

Comment: @David, I am trying your solution and doesn't work for me. It shows again as default value the firs one.

Comment: @user3592644: My solution resolves the error your code was receiving and explains why you were receiving it.  It does not complete your project for you.  I make no promises about the rest of your code or logic.  Again, Stack Overflow questions are not ongoing tutorials to guide you through your entire project.  They are discrete questions about specific issues you encounter.  If you have additional issues in your code, I recommend formulating specific questions regarding those issues.

Comment: @David http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527344/dropdownlist-default-value-pre-selected-during-update