# dropdownList default value pre-selected during update

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 tables :
artikulli

```
tema    varchar(250)    
abstrakti   text
data_publikimit date    
path    varchar(350)    
keywords    varchar(350)    
kategoria_id    int
```

kategoria

```
id  int
emertimi    varchar(350)
```

I have a dropdownList wich displays all "emertimi" and when the user select one it saves the id for that emertimi in table "artikulli" in column "kategoria_id".
My problem is with update. When i perform an update dropdown doesn't displays as default pre-selected the value that exists in database but instead the first value in the list.

```
DropDownList drpdKategoria = e.Item.FindControl("drpdKategoria") as DropDownList;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            string Qry = "select * from kategoria";
            string id = Request.QueryString["id"];                                 
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Qry, con);
            SqlDataAdapter did = new SqlDataAdapter(id, con);               
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            did.Fill(ds);
            string kategoria_id = "select kategoria_id from artikulli where id='" + id + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter dk = new SqlDataAdapter(kategoria_id, con);
            dk.Fill(ds);
            string emertimi = "select emertimi from kategoria where id='" + kategoria_id + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter de = new SqlDataAdapter(emertimi, con);
            de.Fill(ds);
            drpdKategoria.DataSource = ds;
            drpdKategoria.DataValueField = "id";
            drpdKategoria.DataTextField = "emertimi";              
            drpdKategoria.DataBind();               
            var defaultValue = drpdKategoria.Items.FindByText(emertimi);
            if (defaultValue != null)
                drpdKategoria.SelectedValue = defaultValue.Value;
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            ds.Dispose();
            da.Dispose();
            did.Dispose();
            dk.Dispose();
            de.Dispose();
```

What am i doing wrong???

Comment: You need to set on SelectedValue an Integer, are you?

Comment: You're doing the *exact* same thing you did in your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/23526221/328193).  You set the variable `emertimi` to *a SQL query string* and then try to find an element in your `DropDownList` based on that query.  What are the actual text values in your `DropDownList`?  Unless they're SQL queries, `FindByText(emertimi)` isn't going to find anything.  A `DropDownList` is not a database, it can't be queried like one.

Comment: if i change int kat_id = convert.toint32(kategoria_id) it shows this error: formatexception was unhandled by user code

Comment: @user3592644: That's because `"select kategoria_id from artikulli where id='" + id + "'"` can't be converted into an integer.  It's a string of text, not a number.  You seem to be under the impression that strings automatically resolve database queries.  They don't.  They're static scalar values.  Your `DataSet` has the results of your query.

Comment: string emertimi = "select emertimi from kategoria where id='" + kategoria_id + "'"; is supoused to contain the specific value that i want to show because selects emertimi from table kategoria for this id. it's 1 value. How can I do it in different way? without query

Comment: @David and your solution is?

Comment: @user3592644: You're already executing one query and filling a `DataSet` with it (using a `DataAdapter`).  Why don't you execute your other queries the same way?

Comment: @David edited my question and now shows this error: Incorrect syntax near '3081'.

Comment: @David you gave me a suggesstion, now pls take a look

Comment: @user3592644: Honestly, you need to start with some tutorials on how to use ADO.NET data objects. (For starters, your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks, but that's another issue.) Look at how you're building your "select emertimi" query. Specifically `where id='" + kategoria_id + "'"`. Just 3 lines earlier you set `kategoria_id` to a SQL query of its own. So your new query is looking for records where `id` equals *the string of the first query*. I can't stress this enough, *strings do not automatically execute against the database*. Your query is a query, *not* the result of a query.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got you right, but I decided to write because I got many troubles like this one you're describing. If you setted **AutoPostBack=true** for the control *drpdKategoria*, everytime you select a value in it the page refreshs.

If you bind the data to **drpdKategoria** in the Page_Load, you can use this:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

     {
          if (!IsPostBack)

          {
               //bind data here
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at these lines specifically:

```
string kategoria_id = "select kategoria_id from artikulli where id='" + id + "'";
SqlDataAdapter dk = new SqlDataAdapter(kategoria_id, con);
dk.Fill(ds);
string emertimi = "select emertimi from kategoria where id='" + kategoria_id + "'";
```

I'm not sure where you got this idea, but based on the comments above and on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23526221/328193) you seem *really* stuck on the notion that somehow a SQL query string will *become* the result of that query from the database.  It won't.  The string of the SQL query will stay the string.  The *results* of the query, in the way you're using it, will be in the `DataSet` object.

(Note: You're re-using the same `DataSet` object each time.  It's been a while since I've used ADO.NET objects, but I *suspect* that's going to over-write your previous query results every time you re-fill it with new results.  For starters, you may want to at least use separate `DataSet` objects until you get the hang of this.)

So the problem here is that your `emertimi` query is going to look like this:

```
select emertimi from kategoria where id='select kategoria_id from artikulli where id='3081''
```

That query clearly won't work.  Firstly because there's a nested string resulting in a syntax error and secondly because there's no `id` value called the *literal string* `"select kategoria_id from artikulli where id='3081'"`.

The variable `kategoria_id` is just a string.  Even after you execute the query with your `DataAdapter` that's not going to change the string.  The ID value you're looking for, the *result* of the query, is in the `DataSet` object.  You'll want to inspect it to make sure there are values, but in a successful scenario of that first query the ID value will be in:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]
```

This resolves to the first table of the dataset, the first row of that table, the first item in that row.  So you might do something like:

```
var kategoria_id_result = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
string emertimi = "select emertimi from kategoria where id='" + kategoria_id_result + "'"
```

This would use the *result* of the first query as the value of the second query, instead of using *the first query itself* as the value of the second query.  So, *ultimately*, **the value you're *looking for*** to use in setting the default selected item in the `DropDownList` will also be in the results of the SQL query in the `DataSet`, somewhere.  (Probably also in `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]` since the latter SQL query executions overwrite the former ones.)

However, please be aware that there are numerous other problems with your code.  To name a few:

- This code is ***highly vulnerable*** to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.  *Never* treat user input (the `Request.QueryString` value in this case) as *executable SQL code*.  Use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to treat user input as *data* instead of as *code*.  (In the link provided, pay specific attention to the use of the `Parameters` property on the `SqlCommand` objects.)
- Are your `id` values in the database strings or integers?  It's highly likely that they're integers, but your queries are treating them as strings (by wrapping the values in single-quotes).  This will likely result in errors when executing your database queries.
- As mentioned earlier, you're re-using the same `DataSet` by filling it with the results of three separate queries.  This is *probably* overwriting the results of the first two queries and just keeping the results of the last one.
- Make use of [the `using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to properly handle disposable objects.
- *Always* check for `null` values, especially in the weakly-typed world of ADO.NET objects and `DataSet`s.  For example, before you reference `ds.Tables[0]` you'll want to make sure that `ds.Tables.Count` is greater than 0, otherwise you'll get errors.  There are a *lot* more places in your code where you need to perform checks like this.  (For example, at the beginning where you use `FindControl`.  You should make sure the control was found before trying to use it.)
- Your variable names are really difficult to follow.  `ds`, `da`, `did`, `dk`, etc.  You'll find that code is a lot easier to debug when your variable names are meaningful words which describe the purpose of the variable.
- Speaking of debugging, have you used the debugger at all?  Place breakpoints in your code in Visual Studio and examine the runtime values at those points when the application is executing.  This will show you a lot of the problems you're encountering, such as the query within a query mentioned above.
- Look into using [`try`/`catch` blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) to better handle errors, particularly when working with external resources like databases.
- Your SQL executions are all bunched up, it's difficult to tell where one begins and others end.  When interacting with a database, it's best to enclose that code within a single tight block.  Open the connection, fetch the results, close the connection, dispose of the resources.  In that order, without interruption.  Leaving database objects laying around can lead to unexpected behavior in the code.

I hope this answer hasn't come across as overly critical or mean, it's genuinely not intended in that way.  There's just a lot wrong with this code and I want to avoid this single Stack Overflow question from becoming a thread of [help vampirism](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).  Please walk through [some](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [ADO.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET) [tutorials](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet) and patiently examine the objects they're using and what those objects are doing.  Look at the MSDN documentation of the objects and the properties being set on them.  Experiment in small steps, changing one thing at a time and examining how it modifies the runtime behavior of the code (using the debugger).  Understand the code and how it's working.  Don't just copy/paste code samples and expect them to work the way you think they should.

Comment: Well thank you, I appreciate your comment. I am new at this language and I have a school project which I should finish in 1 week. I assure you that I am not some help vampire :p Anyway i have read your comment very carefully and I changed my code. I tried to solve it but without result. I am getting the id of kategoria_id because debug shows this "select emertimi from kategoria where id='6'" but the problem is that emertimi is null :  SqlDataAdapter de = new SqlDataAdapter(emertimi, con);
                de.Fill(ds3);